# jquery ajax returning text of php script instead of json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a php script that works correctly when executed directly:
The PHP:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $fileName = "../appfiles/Courses.json";
    if (file_exists($fileName)) 
      {
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileName), true);
        echo json_encode($json);
      } 
    else 
      {
        echo "The file $fileName does not exist";
      }
    ; 
?>
```

Running

```
http://localhost/RickVideos/php/getRegCourses.php
```

, I get:

```
[{"coursecode":"ACCTD_001","cflag":"Y","pflag":"Y","dateregistered":"08\/11\/14","timeregistered":"12:55 pm."},{"coursecode":"LWPRG1_004","cflag":"Y","pflag":"Y","dateregistered":"08\/18\/14","timeregistered":"3:30 pm."},{"coursecode":"LWPRG2_005","cflag":"Y","pflag":"Y","dateregistered":"08\/18\/14","timeregistered":"3:32 pm."}]
```

Trying to run the php from jquery ajax, what returns seems to be the text of the script rather than the json data.

JavaScript:

```
// registered courses
```

var registeredCourses = {

```
init: function () 
    {
        $.ajax(
            {   
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: "php/getRegCourses.php",
            }
        )

        .done(function(data) 
            { 
                $.each(data, function(index, element) 
                    {
                        $('#registeredCourses').append(
                        $('<option value="' +   index + '">' + this['coursecode'] + '</option>')
                        );
                    }
                );      
                $('#registeredCourses').val('0');
                $("#registeredCourses").trigger('chosen:updated');
                registeredCourses.getSelected();    
            }
        )
        .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )
            {
                alert('request failed :'+errorThrown);
                alert ('textStatus :'+textStatus);
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        );
    },

getSelected: function () 
    {
        $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'GET',
                url: "getSelCourseInfo.php",
                data: 
                    {
                        course: $("#registeredCourses option:selected").text() 
                    }
            }
        )

        .done(function( data ) 
            {
                $("#courseCode").val($("#registeredCourses option:selected").text());
                $("#courseTitle").val(data.Title);
                $("#projectManager").val(data.ProjectManager);                         
                $("#initRegDate").val (data.LastModDate + ' at ' +  data.LastModTime);

                var tasks = [ ];
                $.each(data.ProjectTasks, function(i, item) 
                    {       
                        $("#projectTasks").append(
                            '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + this + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>'
                        );
                        tasks[i] = this;
                    }
                );

                var projectMems = [ ];
                $.each(data.ProjectMembers, function(i, item)
                    {       
                        $("#projectMembers").append(
                            '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + this.PersonName + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + this.EmailAddress + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>'
                        );
                        projectMems[i] = this.PersonName;
                    }
                );

                $("#selectedCourseData").find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                $.each(data.Chapters, function(i, item) 
                    {
                        $("#selectedCourseData").append(
                            '<tr>' +
                            '<td>' + this.label + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + this.title + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + registeredCourses.makeList('Sciptwriter1', i, projectMems, this.ScriptWriter) + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + registeredCourses.makeList('Recorder1', i, projectMems, this.Recorder) + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + registeredCourses.makeList('Status1', i, tasks, this.Status) + '</td>' +
                            '<td>' + registeredCourses.makeList('Assignedto1', i, projectMems, this.Assignedto) + '</td>' +
                            '</tr>'
                        );
                    }
                );

            }
        ); 


    },

    makeList: function (cname, num, array, selected) 
        {
            var string = '<select class="' + cname +'">';
            if (selected== " " && array[0] != " ") 
                {
                array.splice(0, 0, " ");
            };
            for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) 
                {
                    if (array[i]==selected) 
                        {
                            string = string + '<option value="' + array[i] + '" selected>' + array[i]  + '</option>';
                    }
                    else 
                        {
                            string = string + '<option value="' + array[i] + '">' + array[i]  + '</option>';
                    };
            };

            string = string + '</select>';
            return string;
        }

};
```

The first alert shows:

request failed :SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

The second alert shows:

textStatus :parsererror

And the response text for the jqXHR object shows:

```
"<?php header('Content-Type: application/json'); $fileName = "../appfiles/Courses.json"; if (file_exists($fileName)) { $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileName), true); echo json_encode($json); } else { echo "The file $fileName does not exist"; } ; ?> "
```

Why is the text of the script showing rather than the json data?

Comment: It's especially weird, since you mention directly calling the file works correctly.. perhaps here you can find something: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5121589/2433843 If not, check your network window in your browser where you can see if the headers and responses etc are correct.

Comment: Check the first answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012815/jquery-ajax-200-ok-json-parseerror. Also, I noticed in the code you posted you have an unenclosed string: "+ /option>')". It should be: " + '/option')"

Comment: I reposted the code including the missing functions.

Comment: I reran the code after eliminating the dataType from the ajax call and now get this as the first alert result:request failed :Error: Invalid XML: <?php

 

header('Content-Type: application/json');



$fileName = "../appfiles/Courses.json";



if (file_exists($fileName)) 

 {

   $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileName), true);

   echo json_encode($json);

 } 

else 

 {

    echo "The file $fileName does not exist";

 }

;

 

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps or not but the following code works for me. Set up a directory with your json, your php, and an html file for basically just populating the select menu. This works fine for me and when taking a look at your code there were some js errors:

`$('<option value="' + index + '">' + this['coursecode'] +/option>')` is missing the `'<` before the option close tag

Also missing a `}` after you `)` at the end of `fail`. After fixing those files your code worked for me as far as populating the dropdown, though you get js errors because `registeredCourses.getSelected();` doesn't exist. Which makes me wonder if the above code is complete?

If all that doesn't help then have you looked at teh raw html that is output when you go directly to your php file, like viewing the source?

```
`bonk.php`
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $fileName = "courses.json";
    if (file_exists($fileName))
      {
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents($fileName), true);
        echo json_encode($json);
      }
    else
      {
        echo "The file $fileName does not exist";
      }
    ;
?>

`courses.json`
[
    {
        "coursecode": "ACCTD_001",
        "cflag": "Y",
        "pflag": "Y",
        "dateregistered": "08/11/14",
        "timeregistered": "12:55 pm."
    },
    {
        "coursecode": "LWPRG1_004",
        "cflag": "Y",
        "pflag": "Y",
        "dateregistered": "08/18/14",
        "timeregistered": "3:30 pm."
    },
    {
        "coursecode": "LWPRG2_005",
        "cflag": "Y",
        "pflag": "Y",
        "dateregistered": "08/18/14",
        "timeregistered": "3:32 pm."
    }
]

`html file`
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    var registeredCourses = {
      init: function (){
        $.ajax ({
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: "JSON",
          url: "bonk.php",
        })

        .done(function(data){
          $.each(data, function(index, element){
            $('#registeredCourses')
              .append($("<option></option>")
              .attr("value",index)
              .text(this['coursecode']));
          });
        })

        .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
          console.log(errorThrown, textStatus, jqXHR);
        })
      }
    };

    registeredCourses.init();
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select name="test" id="registeredCourses"></select>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I reposted the js code including the missing functions. The js errors mentioned were introduced as I was trying to edit the code in posing the question.

Comment: Viewing the HTML source when accessing the php file directly looks just like the display - there's nothing additional.

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: Current PHP version: 5.4.24

Comment: I got an error running your code that $ isn't defined. I changed the first script to point to js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js and added a $(document).ready(function () { as the first line of the second script and a }); at the end. In firebug, the console shows: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
 

...SON.parse(b+"");var c,d=null,e=m.trim(b+"");return e&&!m.trim(e.replace(xc,funct...

Answer (score 0):

I coverted both the php file and the Courses.json file to utf-8 and it now runs.