# Ajax success callback never executed, parsererror

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a simple AJAX call to a server side PHP script but the success callback is never executed. Instead, under the error callback I get the error 'parsererror'. I've searched stackoverflow and have tried everything but nothing works.

If I try to load the URL to the PHP script with relevant fields, in this case `http://....../matching.php?cmd=generate&N=2&M=3`,  I'll get a proper piece of data in JSON format which is returned. For e.g.

```
{"N":"2","M":"3","E":[[1,1,39],[0,3,100],[2,1,50]]}
```

**AJAX CALL**

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'matching.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'json',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                cmd: "generate",
                N: $('#n1').val(),
                M: $('#n2').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
                leftCount = data.N;
                rightCount = data.M;
                returnedArray = data.E;
                generateFirstPage();
            },
            error: function(request,error) { 
                alert(request.responseText);
                alert(error);
            }
        });

    })
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['cmd'])) {
    $n = $_GET["N"];
    $m = $_GET["M"];
    echo json_encode(generateEdges($n, $m));
    exit;
}

function generateEdges($n, $m) {
    $edgeNumber = rand($n,$n*2);
    $e = array();
    for($i=0; $i<$edgeNumber; $i++) {
        array_push($e, array(rand(0,$n), rand(0,$m), rand(1,100)));
    }
    return $finalArray = array('N' => $n, 'M' => $m, 'E' => $e);
}

?>
```

Doing a `console.log(request.reponseText)` will give

```
{"N":"2","M":"3","E":[[1,0,42],[1,3,48],[0,3,44],[0,0,8]]}
```

Comment: echo json_encode(generateEdges($n, $m)); exit;

Comment: @NabinKunwar i still get a parsererror.

Comment: post console.log(data) ?

Comment: @NabinKunwar refer to edit

Comment: Take out everything in your php file that's not inside the php tag.

Comment: so you have got that extra <html>
<body>

Comment: The script src should be inside the first file, not the second.

Comment: How about putting php codes at the top?

Comment: @jessica the first file is a .js file. why would i put the script src in there? also i've taken out everything that isn't in the php tag. I still get parsererror

Comment: All JavaScript codes should be in the file where you make the Ajax call, or they won't be executed. Are you getting the parse error when you first load the page, or when you first execute the ajax call?

Comment: Got firebug? lets see the whole error message.

Comment: @jessica as mentioned above. the error callback is executed which gives the parsererror

Comment: Why don't you try using regular ajax as oppose to json?

Comment: Use f12 and check in console for more errors.

Comment: @jessica you can explain what regular ajax is as oppose to json. there are no errors in the console. the error has something to do with the data which is being returned. if someone can outrightly tell me that the data being passed back is NOT json when i specified my dataType as json then we all know where the error is. but at this point. it looks like that isn't the case

Comment: [[1,0,42],[1,3,48],[0,3,44],[0,0,8]] Is it valid json ?

Comment: `{"N":"2","M":"3","E":[[1,0,42],[1,3,48],[0,3,44],[0,0,8]]}` this is valid json @NabinKunwar

Comment: another option could be to remove `contentType` and `dataType` and let the ajax call detect it automatically, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16013156/2337692.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the error is that your AJAX call isn't actually hitting your `matching.php` file. I copied your code into 2 files of my own, 1 with the HTML and the javascript included (though I did wrap the javascript with a `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`, but that doesn't seem to be your problem).

When I hit submit, calling my own "matching.php" but leaving that file empty, I get the same `parsererror` you mention. If I then have matching.php execute the code you provided, it hits the success condition and everything is fine. I don't think the issue is the PHP or even your javascript, necessarily, just where it's looking for `matching.php`.

Use Firebug or Chrome's developer javascript console to view the ajax network call to see if it actually hits it. This may just be a symptom of a different problem, but it's worth double checking, imo.