# How to pass a javascript string to the Controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on a project but I have been stuck here for a day now.
In summary the question I have depends only on the **StartPage** of my Project.

I have looked through countless guides even on StackOverflow but to no avail.

---

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Starter</title>

    <style>
        p {
            margin-top: 30%;
            margin-left: 20%;
            margin-right: 20%;
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 25px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #Code {
            border: 2px solid black;
        }
    </style>



</head>
<body>
    <h1>249765876358312345655</h1>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <p>
        Enter a Machine Code:
        <br />
        <input id="Code"
               name="Code"
               pattern=""
               size="30"
               spellcheck="false"
               title="Maschine Code"
               value="">
        <input type="hidden" value="26" name="projectId" />
    </p>


    <script>
            let x = document.getElementById("Code");
        x.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
            x = document.getElementById("Code").value;
            let vars = x;
            let digits = vars.match(/^\d{13}(\d{6})\d{2}$/)[1];
            let stringDigits = digits.toString();

            if (stringDigits.length == 6 && vars.length == 21) {

                window.location.href = '/home/Kontrolle';
                document.getElementById("Code").innerHTML = "";
                localStorage.setItem("Code_Kurz", stringDigits);


                $.ajax({
                    url: "@Url.Action("StartPage")",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: JSON.stringify(stringDigits),
                    dataType: "string",
                    contentType:"StartPage/json",
                    success: function (data) { alert("Succ: " + data); },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText;
                        console.log("ERROR: " + errorMessage);},
                });

            }
        });


    </script>
    }
</body>


</html>
```

To sum that up: the **h1** Tag is a example of this Code witch gets filtered by ReGex -> end result: **123456**

The number **123456** is saved in **stringDigits**.
Now I want to pass **stringDigits** to the Controller.

---

**Controller**

```
namespace Qualitätskontrolle.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult StartPage(string Code)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(Code);
            return View();
}
}
}
```

There in the **StartPage** Controller should the string then appear.

The result should be in the Output window: **123456** but I only get the error message from javascript.

Comment: What does the js error say?

Comment: Its just this line of code but I have no idea what could be wrong ```html error: function () { alert("ERROR" + data); },``` I think it just cant pick up the stringDigits value.

Comment: try to add data in function `error: function (data) { alert("ERROR" + data); }`

Comment: Don't `alert` errors. Use `console.log` instead if you want to see some details about your errors.

Comment: I did and now it says **ERROR[object Object]** as expected

Comment: @Cerbrus I will remove the alerts as soon as it starts working I now the alerts are really annoying.

Comment: @KlausK: `alert` is ___horrible___ to see what a JS object contains. It can only show text. If you want to log an object, use `console.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have now edited the start Question except the error.
I know the answer:

"Try to remove contentType and dataType from Ajax parameters and let them be identified automatically" ~ Catalin

These two should be removed:

```
 dataType: "string",
```

```
contentType:"StartPage/json",
```

See:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16013156/11754349

Answer (score 2):

There are several issue here.

- You are returning `View` to an ajax call. You should probably `return Json("Content", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`.
- You are setting `dataType: JSON.stringify(stringDigits)`. You can remove this bit
- You are setting `data: "string"`. It should be `data: { Code: stringDigits }`, because `StartPage` expects parameter named `Code` as an input.
- You are redirecting just before the AJAX `window.location.href = '/home/Kontrolle'` (Not sure why)
- The error handler uses variable `data` that isn't defined in that context. Unlike success handler, the one for error does not receive `data` as an input. Here is an example of a correct error handling:

  ```
  error: function (xhr, status, error) {
      var errorMessage = xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText;
      console.log("ERROR: " + errorMessage);
  }
  ```

There are several simple examples here: [ASP.NET MVC controller actions that return JSON or partial html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227624)

```
public ActionResult StartPage(string code) 
{ 
    return Json(new { foo="bar" });
}
```

In JS:

```
$.getJSON(url, { code: stringDigits },
    function(data) {
        alert(data.foo);
    }
);
```

Comment: if you just copy the thing about error handling from my answer below, i'd remove mine, cause we go over similar things

Comment: @Andrei yours seems much more detailed. You should keep it

Comment: I merged them anyway, it makes more sense to have one complete answer than two partial ones

Comment: @adiga I have now tried your error handeling and it said: **ERROR: 200: parsererror** Note: stringDigits already has the correct number in it.

Answer (score 1):

From your code, I found that you have provided **stringDigits** in dataType instead of the data property. Maybe this caused the problem. So, please correct that code like as follows,

```
dataType: "string",
data: JSON.stringify(stringDigits)
```

Comment: I did it but to now avail sadly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the ajax call or use a input hidden field that fill with your data
and you can call action in controller use URL and pass data use the query string
example http://www.domin.com/controller/action?data=1234567
in java script can call url use :
window.location=Url;